If for an n-order matrix A, the algebraic multiplicity of the 0 eigenvalue is n, then how many non-zero elements can there be at most in A?
For example:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1\\
 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For this matrix, the algebraic multiplicity of the 0 eigenvalue is 2, and there is one non-zero element in it.
We can find that all the elements on the main diagonal of matrix A are zero, and matrix A is an upper triangular matrix. Therefore, I conjecture that the non-zero elements number k satisfies the following inequality:
$$
k\le \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
But how to prove it?

You’re asking about Algebraic multiplicity, not geometric. For geometric multiplicity $n$, you can only have the $0$ matrix. The matrices you’re asking about are called Nilpotent

If I understand correctly, your claim is this (I supposed you meant algebraic multiplicity instead of geometric multiplicity as given by your example):

Claim: Suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $0$ is the only eigenvalue, of algebraic multiplicity $n$. Then the number of non-zero entries of the matrix $A$ is smaller or equal to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

This claim is false: $A = \begin{pmatrix}1&7&-8\\1&3&-4\\1&3&-4\end{pmatrix}$ is a matrix such that $A^3 = 0$, thus $0$ is the only eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity $3$, yet all of its entries are non-zero.
Perhaps your claim came from looking at strictly upper/lower triangular matrices only, yet any matrix that is similar to a strictly upper/lower triangular matrix has the same algebraic and geometric multiplicity for every eigenvalue. I found this example by playing with Wolfram Alpha (https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B1%2C3%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D%7B%7B0%2C1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%7D%7DPower%5B%7B%7B1%2C3%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C1%7D%7D%2C-1%5D)

Your conjecture is wrong. For example $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ -1& -1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
To construct such a matrix you can first consider a matrix whose rows are different just with a scalar. The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is:
$\lambda^n -tr(A)\lambda^{n-1}$. Now, if you make the trace zero, you get a matrix with no zero entries whose characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^n$; that is, the algebraic multiplicity of zero in $n$.

The answer is $n^2$. The lesson is that matrices with nice properties need not have nice entries. E.g.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\pi &e\\ 1&\gamma
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\ 0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}\pi &e\\ 1&\gamma
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}3.47&-10.9\\1.11&-3.47
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You could have chosen pretty much anything for the simlarity transformation and almost always end up with all nonzero entries. Note: A matrix entry is zero if its column vector is parallel to some coordinate axis. This has little to do with the "structure" of the matrix.

But maybe there some gaps between $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ and $n^2$. For example, a $2\times 2$ nilpotent matrix cannot have exactly 3 nonzero entries.
